# Do I have to allocate view when I make app without IB?

Tags: iphone

I want to make window based app without using IB.
I created MyViewController by allocating it.
Do I have to create view inside MyViewController also?
Without allocating it, app crashes.
For UITableViewController, UINavigationController,... I don't have to allocate view.
What is difference?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    viewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
    viewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view]; // app crashes here without allocating view explicitly
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should either allocate the view explicitly just as you shown in your code or implement "loadView" in your controller so that the view is created when it is first shown on screen.

Comment: Do I have to allocate view when I make UITableViewController, UINavigationController?

Comment: for UITableViewController - YES for UINavigationController - No as UINavigationController itself is initialized with another ViewController and alone UINavigationController does not have any view. It is the controller's view that becomes Navigation Controller's view after initilization

Answer (score 0):

```
MyViewController *_myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

_myViewController.view = myView
[myView release];
[self.window addSubview:myViewController.view];
```